# Is it possible to host SQLite as a separate process

Tags: sqlite

If we have 500 processes accessing SQLite, is it possible to host it as a separate process, so all 500 processes do not have to perform IO.
These processes can attach to one instance of SQLite and access data. Is it possible twith SQLite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no. SQLite isn't a client/server database, it's just code linked into your application/process. There are 3rd party client/server implementations of SQLite, but I've never used one and can't speak to their quality. It sounds like you may be better off looking at client/server dbs such as PostgreSQL or MySQL.

It might also be worth reading [Appropriate Uses For SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html) to see if your particular use case is a good fit for SQLite or not.